# Как записывать все что должно выводиться в консоль, но при этом в консоль ничего не выводить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я запускаю работать задачу в фоне такой командой:

```
nohup node /folder/script.js arg1 arg2 arg3 2>/dev/null >/dev/null & echo $!;
```

Задача запускается и работает в фоне, после запуска задачи я получаю pid процесса. Здесь все отлично работает.

Хотелось бы в эту команду добавить чтобы все что должно отображаться в консоли (все что печатает запущенная программа) сохранялось в лог-файл.

Буду очень благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Очевидно, надо заменить пункт назначения потока `/dev/null` на желаемый. `&> filename`

Comment: @user207200 а почему вместо `>2` вы указываете `&>` ?

Comment: Перенаправление `&>filename` направляет оба потока в `filename`. Это то же самое, что `>filename 2>&1` (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)